# Distance from a point to a polyhedron or to a polygon

Tags: math, geometry, algebra

I have a surface which is a polyhedron and I want to find the minimal distance between it and a given point ***P***. Since the polyhedron is defined by many polygons in a 3d space, one way that occurs to me is to compare the distance to each polygon and choose the shortest distance. Still I am not sure about it.

Comment: Is the polyhedra convex?

Comment: At the beginning yes, but in the future might not need to be.

Comment: Do you mean **polyhedron**? A surface composed of polyhedra imply you have several polyhedrons.

Comment: You are right, I am sorry, my mistake.

Comment: I think the Gilbert–Johnson–Keerthi distance algorithm is probably what I need (probably I can reduce the problem to a convex object always), however I haven't find any implementations of this algorithm.

Comment: @Samba: If you need implementation, at least show us which program you'll use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implementations of Gilbert–Johnson–Keerthi:
http://www.comlab.ox.ac.uk/stephen.cameron/distances/gjk2.4/
http://code.google.com/p/gjkd/