# How calculate the distance and arrival time to a polyline?

Tags: java, android

How i can to make to calculate distance and time between my current location and near polyline?, below I attached a sample image

[image]

Comment: The figure seems misleading. Is the target a polyline (i.e. a connected sequence of individual lines) or a functional (polygonal or similar) curve?

Comment: It would be a tour in google maps, as the gogole maps route creates, the idea is that from my current location I found the near point of the line created in the route

Comment: In that case, sounds much the same as [Distance from a point to a polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983872/distance-from-a-point-to-a-polygon). Note that the JTS implements the [minimum distance for all supported geometry types](http://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/Geometry.html#distance(org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry)), in case you want to re-use an existing library.